# Como restar entre 2 horas en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Estoy utilizando Codeigniter y deseo hacer una resta en la vista.

```
<?php
    $cadena = strtotime($seguimiento->horaInicio);
    $cadena = date("H:i", $cadena);
    echo $cadena;

    $cadena2 = strtotime($seguimiento->horaTermino);
    $cadena2 = date("H:i", $cadena2);
    echo $cadena2;

    $res = abs($cadena - $cadena2);
    echo $res;
?>
```

En caso que la hora sea     `11:30 16:15` el resultado debería ser `4,85` pero en vez me muestra `5`. Espero haberme explicado bien.

```
   var HDesde = $(this).data("inicio");
       var HHasta = $(this).data("fin");


       // var dia = $(this).data("dia");
       // if (i=0) { fecha = dia; }

       hora1 = (HDesde).split(":");
       hora2 = (HHasta).split(":");
       HoraDesde=(hora1[0]);
       MinutoDesde=(hora1[1]);
       HoraHasta=(hora2[0]);
       MinutoHasta=(hora2[1]);
       TotDesde=parseInt((HoraDesde*60)) + parseInt(MinutoDesde);
       TotHasta=parseInt(HoraHasta*60) + parseInt(MinutoHasta);
       RestaHoras=(TotHasta - TotDesde);
       TotHorasTrab=(RestaHoras / 60).toFixed(2);

       $(this).html(TotHorasTrab);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podría servirte la funcion [**diff**](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) de php.

> Devuelve la diferencia entre dos objetos DateTimeInterface.

```
$horaInicio = new DateTime($cadena);
$horaTermino = new DateTime($cadena2);

$interval = $horaInicio->diff($horaTermino);
echo $interval->format('%H horas %i minutos %s seconds');
```

---

La variable `$interval` viene a ser del tipo [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php); si deseas operar con eso variable, por ejemplo para sumarla a otra fecha puedes usar la función [**add**](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php):

```
$nuevaFecha = new DateTime('2018-07-04 00:00:00');
$nuevaFecha->add($interval);
echo $nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero he intentado hacerlo con diff y recibo este error `Message: Call to a member function diff() on string`

Comment: Me responde con el mismo error

Comment: Me resta bien pero no puedo realizar una suma después con el variable `$interval`. Gracias por tu ayuda de todo modos

Comment: Para eso se tiene que usar otra función, editare mi respuesta agregando eso tambien

Comment: No seria echo `echo $nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: `Message: Undefined variable: nuevaFecha` y cuando cree le variable `Message: Call to a member function add() on string`

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

La cuestión es que necesitas dos objetos `DateTime` válidos para usar `diff`. A partir de ahí podrás obtener un objeto [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) con `diff`. Luego puedes aprovechar las propiedades de ese objeto para hacer los cálculos que necesites.

Por ejemplo:

```
$fechaUno=new DateTime('11:30');
$fechaDos=new DateTime('16:15');

$dateInterval = $fechaUno->diff($fechaDos);
echo $dateInterval->format('Total: %H horas %i minutos %s segundos').PHP_EOL;
```

Tienes la salida:

```
Total: 04 horas 45 minutos 0 segundos
```

Si revisas por dentro tu objeto `$dateInterval` verás lo que contiene:

Hacemos un `var_dump($dateInterval);` y tendremos:

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(4)
  ["i"]=>
  int(45)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Supongamos que ahora quieres calcular la cantidad de minutos que tiene. Aplicas cálculos adecuados a las propiedades `d, h, i` del objeto (días, horas, minutos):

```
$totalMinutos=($dateInterval->d * 24 * 60) + ($dateInterval->h * 60) + $dateInterval->i;
echo "Total minutos: $totalMinutos";
```

Tendrás en la salida:

```
Total minutos: 285
```

---

### Otra forma

Otra cosa que podrías hacer sería obtener el timestamp de los dos objetos, restar su valor y hacer operaciones con él.

Veamos:

```
$totalSegundos = abs($fechaUno->getTimestamp() - $fechaDos->getTimestamp());
$totalMinutos=$totalSegundos/60;

echo "Total segundos: $totalSegundos";
echo PHP_EOL;

echo "Total minutos: $totalMinutos";
echo PHP_EOL;

echo "Representación Horas,Minutos: ".gmdate("H:i", $totalSegundos);
```

La salida en este caso sería:

```
Total segundos: 17100
Total minutos: 285
Representación Horas,Minutos: 04:45
```

---

### Cálculo acumulativo usando un bucle

Vamos a suponer que tu objeto es parecido a este.

Puedes crear una función que te calcule el total de segundos, vas acumulando en la variable y al final usas ese total para representar los datos como los necesites:

```
/*Simulacro de tu objeto*/
$seguimiento=(object)array(
                            (object)array("horaInicio"=>"11:30", "horaTermino"=>"16:15"),
                            (object)array("horaInicio"=>"10:00", "horaTermino"=>"11:00")
                           );
/*Variable acumulativa*/
$totalSegundos=0;
foreach($seguimiento as $item){
    /*Se incrementa cada vez con lo que arroje la función calculateTime*/
    $totalSegundos+=calculateTime($item->horaInicio,$item->horaTermino);
}

/*Prueba de datos resultantes*/
echo "Total segundos: $totalSegundos";
echo PHP_EOL;

$totalMinutos=$totalSegundos/60;

echo "Total minutos: $totalMinutos";
echo PHP_EOL;

echo "Representación Horas,Minutos: ".gmdate("H:i", $totalSegundos);

/*Función que es llamada cada vez desde el bucle*/
function calculateTime($horaUno, $horaDos){
    $fechaUno=new DateTime($horaUno);
    $fechaDos=new DateTime($horaDos);
    $diff = abs($fechaUno->getTimestamp() - $fechaDos->getTimestamp());
    return $diff;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Total segundos: 20700
Total minutos: 345
Representación Horas,Minutos: 05:45
```

Comment: Solo quiero restar las horas y minutos

Comment: La diferencia total te la da por ejemplo `$totalSegundos` y a partir de ahí puedes elegir lo que hacer con el dato, si representarlo con un formato dado, si sacar cuántos minutos hay, cuantas horas, cuantos días, etc, @MoteCL

Comment: perdón plantee mal mi respuesta, quería decir que después de hacer la resta el resultado deseo sumarlo ya que recorro en un foreach

Comment: Pero ¿sumarlo a qué a otro objeto `DateTime` o a un valor numérico, o a un acumulador...?

Comment: `echo $dateInterval->format('Total: %H horas %i minutos %s segundos').PHP_EOL;` poder acumular el resultado `$totalsub+=$dateInterval;`

Comment: @MoteCL es que en este caso `$dateInterval` es un objeto (lo puedes ver en la salida del `var_dump`). Dependiendo de lo que sea `$totalsub` (¿es un total de minutos de segundos, de horas?), le puedes añadir sea el total de segundos, o de minutos (yo haría todo usando los segundos) y al final del bucle entonces usas el total que se ha acumulado y lo representas como quieras. Con la función `gmdate`  lo puedes representar como lo desees.

Comment: En caso `11:30 16:15` el resultado debería ser `4,85` el próximo  seria  `10:00 11:00` resultado `1` el total seria `5,85`, solo quiero saber la diferencia de hora y minutos

Comment: @MoteCL ¿cómo `4,85`?, entre las `11:30` y las `16:15` hay `4 horas y 45 minutos`... en cuanto a lo del bucle haré un ejemplo y ahora te muestro.

Comment: @MoteCL revisa la nueva edición de la respuesta, en el apartado **Cálculo acumulativo usando un bucle**.

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo utilizar un paquete llamado Carbon, esta es su documentación https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/, es lo mejor que he visto para trabajar con fechas en php.

Ejemplo:

```
<code>
dt = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 31, 0);

//para sumar
echo $dt->addHours(24);                  // 2012-02-04 00:00:00
echo $dt->addHour();                     // 2012-02-04 01:00:00

//para restar
echo $dt->subHour();                     // 2012-02-04 00:00:00
echo $dt->subHours(24);                  // 2012-02-03 00:00:00
</code>
```

Comment: sería  genial que añadas un ejemplo, pues con solo colocar un enlace tu respuesta es de muy baja calidad, gracias por apoyar a la comundad te recomiendo leer como responder https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: gracias mirare un poco la documentacion

Answer (score -1):

while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
                {

```
            $respuesta = DEFINE('HraInicio','HraFinalizacion');


            $apertura = new DateTime(HraInicio);
            $cierre = new DateTime(HraFinalizacion);

            $tiempo = $apertura->diff($cierre);

            echo $tiempo->format('%H:%I');
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te recomiendo que leas [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que así puedas dar una respuesta mejor, ya que no estás dando contexto de nada, fuera de eso te invito a que hagas el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que así puedas ganar tu primera [medalla!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) y así aprender más del sitio