# Operación de resta

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo estos dos campos que guardan hora de inicio y hora de fin, necesito restar la hora fin con la hora de inicio para así saber cuanto se demoro en hacer su actividad tengo la operación de las variables pero me sale el siguiente error

al ingresar las horas debería hacer la resta y mostrarme que la resta de estas dos fue de 2:50 es decir que me demore 2:50 dos horas y cincuenta minutos haciendo la actividad
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá me muestra los datos que se guardan en la bd donde esta la hora en rojo es donde debiera traerme el resultado de la operación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código para campos de formulario**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label >Hora Inicio</label>
   <input style="border-radius: 5px;" type="time" name="hinicio" class="form-control"  >
    </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
 <label >Hora Fin</label>
  <input style="border-radius: 5px;" type="time" name="hfin" class="form-control"  >
   </div>
```

**código para crear tabla y traer datos**

```
<table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
<thead>
    <tr class="headings">
        <th title="Codigo de la tarea" class="column-title">Codigo</th>
        <th title="Nombre de la tarea" class="column-title">Tarea</th>
        <th title="Nombre de la actividad" class="column-title">Actividad</th>
        <th title="Quien realiza la actividad" class="columntitle">Realiza</th>
        <th  class="column-title">Estado</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th title="Hora Inicio Actividad" class="column-title">H Inicio</th>
        <th title="Hora Inicio Actividad" class="column-title">H Fin</th>
         <th title="Hora Inicio Actividad" class="column-title">Tiempo</th>
        <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr"></span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <?php 
     while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      $id=$r['id'];
       $codigo=$r['codigo'];
        $title=$r['title'];
         $project_id=$r['project_id'];
          $realiza_id=$r['realiza_id'];
           $status_id=$r['status_id'];
            $hinicio=date('h:i:s', strtotime($r['hinicio']));
             $hfin=date('h:i:s', strtotime($r['hfin']));
              $created_at=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($r['created_at']));
               $description=$r['description'];
                $tiempo=$r['tiempo'];
                 $category_id=$r['category_id'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from tareas where id=$project_id");
    if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name_project=$c['name'];
                       }


    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from realiza where id=$realiza_id");
     if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $name_realiza=$c['name'];
                             }


     $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from status where id=$status_id");
     if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $name_status=$c['name'];
                           }
                    ?>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" id="id<?php echo $id;?>">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $codigo;?>" id="codigo<?php echo $id;?>">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $title;?>" id="title<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tiempo;?>" id="tiempo<?php echo $id;?>">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hinicio;?>" id="hinicio<?php echo $id;?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hfin;?>" id="hfin<?php echo $id;?>">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $description;?>" id="description<?php echo $id;?>">
<!-- me obtiene los datos -->
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $project_id;?>" id="project_id<?php echo $id;?>">
       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $realiza_id;?>" id="realiza_id<?php echo $id;?>">
       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $category_id;?>" id="category_id<?php echo $id;?>">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $status_id;?>" id="status_id<?php echo $id;?>">

<tr class="even pointer">
 <td><?php echo $codigo;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $name_project; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $title;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $name_realiza;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $name_status;?></td>
       <td><?php echo $created_at;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hinicio;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $hfin;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $tiempo;?></td>
            <td ><span class="pull-right">
<a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Editar producto' onclick="obtener_datos('<?php echo $id;?>');" data-toggle="modal"
                           data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-udp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a> 
<a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Borrar producto' onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id; ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> </a></span></td>
 </tr>
```

**código de insertar datos, donde esta la operación**

```
   $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
            $title = $_POST["title"];
            $description = $_POST["description"];
            $category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
            $project_id = $_POST["project_id"];
            $realiza_id = $_POST["realiza_id"];
            $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
            $status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
            $hinicio=$_POST["hinicio"];
            $hfin=$_POST["hfin"];
            $tiempo= $hfin - $hinicio;
            $created_at="NOW()";

            // $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

            $sql="insert into actividad (codigo,title,description,hinicio,hfin,tiempo,project_id,realiza_id,user_id,status_id,created_at)
 value (\"$codigo\",\"$title\",\"$description\",\"$hinicio\",\"$hfin\",\"$project_id\",$user_id,$status_id,$realiza_id,$created_at,$tiempo)";
```

acá el error que me sale la linea 25 es donde esta la operación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como restar entre 2 horas en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177803/como-restar-entre-2-horas-en-php)

Comment: No es pregunta duplicada, ya que claramente se ve que tiene javaScript, hay que detallar que son parecidas, mas no tienen nada que ver una con la otra

Comment: A donde vez algo de Java en la pregunta que coooque?

Comment: Correcion JavaScript pero aun asi no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, ya que si miras es totalmente distinto el enfoque+

Comment: Listo muchas gracias

Comment: Según leo en el error no es problema de php si no de la base de datos. Estás intentando actualizar la base de datos donde tienes una foreign key y va a ser que no puedes hacer eso, al menos no en la tabla que lo haces. Mira cuales son los campos afectados por esa key y no los actualices en el php.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Emerita pero miro los campos afectados arreglo esa key y luego me sale la siguiente y no puedo eliminar todas las relaciones

Comment: Ya vi, tenias mal la variable $tiempo, como dijo @MarioGuiber. Un saludo.

Comment: Es correcto, @Emerita muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para restar dos variables que contienen unos horas y deseas saber el tiempo que pasa entre una hora y otra puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$horaInicio = new DateTime('$_POST["hinicio"]'); //08:30
$horaFin = new DateTime('$_POST["hfin"]'); //11:20

$dateInterval = $horaInicio->diff($horaFin);
$tiempo = $dateInterval->format('Total: %H horas %i minutos');
echo $tiempo; //Total: 02 horas 50 minutos
```

Luego veo que a la hora de hacer el **insert into** en la BD, la variable `$tiempo` no la estas colocando en la posición donde corresponde, debe ir así:

```
 $sql="insert into actividad (codigo,title,description,hinicio,hfin,tiempo,project_id,realiza_id,user_id,status_id,created_at)
 values (\"$codigo\",\"$title\",\"$description\",\"$hinicio\",\"$hfin\",\"$tiempo\",\"$project_id\",$user_id,$status_id,$realiza_id,$created_at)";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió para resolver el problema.